# Unable to get a value serialized from .NET from memcached bucket using Java or Rest api

Tags: java, rest, memcached, key-value, couchbase

I am trying to retrieve a value from a memcached Couchbase bucket using the Java SDK without success. The value was serialized from .NET  Is it possible to do this using the REST API?

In couchbase buckets, you just need to send a get request like this:

`SERVER_IP:8091/couchBase/COUCHBASE_BUCKET_NAME/KEY`

and the value is returned.

I have a memcached value, and even though I have the keys, I cannot extract any values.
When in "COUCHBASE_BUCKET" I put the name of the memcached bucket i get 404 not found.

I tried a lot of variations like `/pools/buckets`, or `pools/default/bucket` before memcached bucket name, but with no success.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

In a comment, user scalabilitysolved suggested to use the Java api, which was my first choice

```
client = new CouchbaseClient(nodes, "Bucket", "password");
Object getObject = client.get("1key");
// Print the value from synchronous get
if (getObject != null) {
    System.out.println("Synchronous Get Suceeded: ");;
} else {
    System.err.println("Synchronous Get failed");
}
System.out.println(getObject);
```

the response in console is this:

```
2014-01-17 09:17:40.421 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseMemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=xxxxxxxxx:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-01-17 09:17:40.430 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient:  CouchbaseConnectionFactory{, bucket='Bucket', nodes=[http://xxxxxxx:8091/pools], order=RANDOM, opTimeout=2500, opQueue=16384, opQueueBlockTime=10000, obsPollInt=10, obsPollMax=500, obsTimeout=5000, viewConns=10, viewTimeout=75000, viewWorkers=1, configCheck=10, reconnectInt=1100, failureMode=Redistribute, hashAlgo=NATIVE_HASH}
2014-01-17 09:17:40.431 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient:  viewmode property isn't defined. Setting viewmode to production mode
2014-01-17 09:17:40.431 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseMemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@127fe8ac
2014-01-17 09:17:40.489 INFO net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread:  Authenticated to /xxxxxx:11210
Synchronous Get failed
null
```

Comment: http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/rest-api-getting-data

Comment: i have already had a look on that, but didn't find the answer.Have you?

Comment: Why not just use one of the sdks?

Comment: i used the java sdk, with no success. in detail: I use client.get(KEY), where KEY is the string key, the way I see it in Top keys table, via the HTTP page , for the specific bucket.
The error I am getting is this: WARN net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder: Undecodeable with flags fa00
 return object is null.

This means that the memcached bucket seems to have an alternative behavior.

Comment: Well the java sdk works for me with memcached buckets, edit your question to include the java code you were using to set and get the key. The more detail the better, the rest api route you are taking is 100% not the direction to go in.

Comment: @scalabilitysolved :why do you think that the rest api is not the right direction? regarding the Java api, i am out of office now, but the code was like this: i used client.get(KEY), and i had a try, catch to detect if i was receiving a null object. I was getting a null object, and in addition, as i wrote above, i was getting this message:WARN net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder: Undecodeable with flags fa00. For complete code block, we will have to wait unfortunately, till tomorrow, when i'll return to office

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool Couchbase is designed for administration through the Rest api and data/view access through the sdks.  Post the code you used tomorrow. CouchDB shares the same view structure and is rest based data access, perhaps that is better for you.

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool The answer is no, you cant get values directly from rest api. As you mentioned values there can be stored with different flags, so they need some post processing. But in most cases those flags means nothing and you just need to look if there is an option to ignore them in your client api. I didn't use Couchbase java sdk, but as I wrote below, C# and node.js clients have such feature.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your probably having trouble is because the Couchbase Java SDK serializes data before storing it into Couchbase (and memcached). In order to know how the data was serialized the SDK uses the flags field in the message to indicate how the data is serialized.

It sounds like you have some weird value in your flags field which is causing the Java SDK to not know what to do with the data since it sees an unexpected value in the flags field.

My guess is that you set the data into Couchbase using something other the the Java SDK. The first thing I would do is to only use the Java SDK to make sure you can set and retrieve data.

Comment: Hello mikewied. This is probably the reason, since the dev team stores stuff into memcache using .NET api.This serialiazation thing, happens for the reasons you described, and happens for couchbase and memcaceh buckets. However if I use the Java api, to set a new document  and get it , it works. Since our test infrastructure uses java,I need to use java, to retrieve values. In the case of couchbase bucket, i bypassed this problem, by sending a get request (written in java).However i cannot do the same for the memcached bucket.

Comment: I had problem with flags with C# and Node.js client, but after some time Node.js client was patched for manually setting flags, so maybe Java SDK have the same option to set flags.

Comment: You should be able to turn off serialization somehow. That's really your only option if you want to use both SDK's at the same time because even if you were to get the flags fields to match with both SDK's then the next issue you would have would be that each language would likely serialize similar types in different way. I can ask around to figure out the best way to handle this. I'll try to post back later.

Comment: After asking around the recommendation for how to store values when using multiple SDK's is to store everything in JSON and not serialize any of the data.